# Where to place my drawable to maintain high-quality?

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I am testing my Apps on Galaxy Note3, and while reading a book I found the below posted table, and the questions occurred to my mind are,

1)which folder should I use to maintain the `drawable` or it does not matter using any of them?

2)According to the table below, does placing my `drawables` in, for a example, `ldpi` folder cause it to be of low-quality?

[image]

Comment: `ìdpi` is not a valid qualifier. It is `ldpi` with a `l` like *low*

Comment: @ben75 thank you, I chaged it

Answer (score 0):

You should paste your images with best resolution in **drawable-hdpi**. Android will automatically  optimize it down to the required resolution according to the density of device.

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) states that Android supports bitmap files in a three formats: .png (preferred), .jpg (acceptable), .gif (discouraged).

> It also states that Bitmap files may be automatically optimized with lossless image compression by the     aapt tool during the build process. For example, a true-color PNG that does not require more than 256 colors may be converted to an 8-bit PNG with a color palette. This will result in an image of equal quality but which requires less memory. So be aware that the image binaries placed in this directory can change during the build. If you plan on reading an image as a bit stream in order to convert it to a bitmap, put your images in the res/raw/ folder instead, where they will not be optimized.

So, we should also care about the image type used !